# Python date formatting without space?

Tags: python, time

How to display the following without any space also could we substitute a separator instead of space?

```
> log_time=datetime.datetime.now()
> print log_time
2009-12-16 16:10:03.558991
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datetime.date.strftime()`.

Answer (score 36):

This works like a charm!

**Without any separator**

> ```
> import datetime
> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
> ```

**Using - as separator**

> ```
> import datetime
> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
> ```

**Using _ as separator**

> ```
> import datetime
> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression

```
import datetime
import re

print( re.sub("\D", "", str(datetime.datetime.now())) )
```

or use the join method

```
print( ''.join(i for i in str(datetime.datetime.now()) if i.isdigit()) )
```